# MFC Multibyte Add-on for Visual Studio 2015 Express for Desktop

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-express, mbcs

I'm using [VS 2015 Express for Desktop](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615464&clcid=0x419) which doesn't have MFC Multibyte support by default.

Not long ago there was a separate [MFC MBCS DLL Add-on](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=286820).

But now link to [Multibyte MFC Library for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44930) is removed.

That was done because all other VS editions have "Microsoft Foundation Classes for C++" optional install component:

[image: "MFC" optional feature]

But VS 2015 Express for Desktop lacks it (it has no optional install components, no "Custom" installation at all)
So the questions are:

1. Maybe someone has a backup link to the download Multibyte MFC Library for Visual Studio 2015?
2. I've also downloaded [VS 2015 Community Edition ISO](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615448&clcid=0x409). In the **\packages\VisualC_D14** there are several **VC_MFC.*** folders (**VC_MFC.MBCS** among them). But trying to run executables inside that folder leads to an error

[image]

Maybe someone knows howto install that components without running whole VS 2015 Community Edition setup?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. Installing VS 2015 Community Edition instead of VS 2015 Express for Desktop is not suitable for my company due to license limitations (we are enterprise organization - over 250 PCs - and use VS for commercial purposes).

Unfortunately changing the character set from multibyte to Unicode in our projects is also not an option for us now.

Comment: I can't find details on VS 2915 Express, but Express editions never supported add-ins, and did not include MFC.

Comment: Sad to hear such bad news..

Comment: `we are enterprise organization - over 250 PCs - and use VS for commercial purposes` IANAL but mind the [license](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/legal/mt171551.aspx): "_you must comply with any technical limitations in the software that only allow you to use it in certain ways ... you may not extend the software by, among other things, loading or injecting into the software any non-Microsoft add-ins, macros, or packages; modifying the software registry settings; **or adding features or functionality equivalent to that found in other Visual Studio products.**_".

Comment: @dxiv Oh, looks like I've missed it

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution for this. kindly follow the steps to add MFC for C++

- step 1: close any Opened Visual Studio.
- Step 2: open a Visual Studio and choose File->New -> Project
- Step 3: In New Project Pop UP, Select Templates->Visual C++ -> MFC
- Step 4: In the Listed Project/files, you will see "Install Microsoft
  Foundation classes for C++". Double Click on it.
- Step 5: "Install Missing Features" Popup Come with two Button
  "Install and Cancel". Saying "Install Microsoft Foundation Classes
  for C++. You Simple Click on "Install".
- Step 6: Important "Close the opened VS" and you will see Visual
  Studio Setup Wizard come with option "Microsoft Foundation Classes"
  Within Features Tab. Just Click on "Next" and then a new Window
  Appear click on "Update". Your MFC will start updating.
- Step 7: Enjoy coding.....

Comment: This does not seem to work for the Express editions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see my installation the files are always installed if you install the MFC.

I just rechecked it on a different machine. The appropriate MBCS libs are installed by Default, when you choose MFC in the installation of VS-2015.

Comment: Are you talking about VS 2015 Express? Is doesn't have "MFC" optional feature during installation.

Comment: I am talking about the pay-Versions. I don't have the express version,

Comment: I just get the confirmation from a colleague that the Community Edition contains the MFC MBCS libs too.

Comment: I already know it, thx. But that is not an option for me. I need to make MFC MBCS work with Express edition somehow

Comment: What is the problem switching to the community edition?

Comment: "In enterprise organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue), no use is permitted beyond the open source, academic research, and classroom learning". We are enterprise company and use VS for commercial purposes

Comment: Than just get a MSDN abonement!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87025/discussion-between-bairog-and-xmri).